# Property [stats] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am new in laravel and I got this error

> Property [stats] does not exist on this collection instance. (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\enginepoker2\resources\views\pages\players.blade.php)

this is in players.blade.php

```
@foreach ($player_stats->stats as $player_stat)

                        <tr class="gradeX">
                        <td><a href="">{{ $player_stat->username }}</a></td>
                        <td>{{ $player_stat->country }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $player_stat->rank }}</td>
                        <td class="center"><a href="#" class="name" data-name="winpot" data-pk="{{ $player_stat->ID }}" data-type="text" data-url="{{ route('updatePlayer') }}">{{ number_format($player_stat->winpot, 2, ',', '.') }}</a></td>
                        <td class="center"><a href="#" class="name" data-name="freeGames" data-pk="{{ $player_stat->ID }}" data-type="text" data-url="{{ route('updatePlayer') }}">{{ $player_stat->freeGames }}</a></td>
                            <td class="center"><a href="#" class="name" data-name="transferLimit" data-pk="{{ $player_stat->ID }}" data-type="text" data-url="{{ route('updatePlayer') }}">{{ number_format($player_stat->transferLimit, 2, ',', '.') }}</a></td>

                        </tr>

                        @endforeach
```

this is in controller

```
use App\players;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class playerController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {       
        $player_stats = players::where('bot', '=', '0')->orderBy('ID', 'DESC')->limit('500')->get();
        return view('pages.players', [ 'player_stats'=>$player_stats]);

    }
}
```

this is in players model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class players extends Model
{
    protected $player = 'players';

    public function stats()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(stats::class);
    }

}
```

this is in stats model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class stats extends Model
{
    protected $player = 'stats';

    public function players()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(players::class);
    }    
}
```

Comment: what you get when doing `dd($player_stats)` ?

Comment: I get like this https://drive.google.com/open?id=1th-QmOzeKlGfdf9njPGxQbw_fPIt65vD

Answer (score 0):

First i think you should change first naming of your model with Capitalize name. I mean change class player to class Player and class stats to class Stats.

Second, use namespacing when try to add relation in laravel. Try change.

```
public function stats()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(stats::class);
}
```

to

```
public function stats()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Stats');
}
```

also change the

```
public function players()
{
   return $this->hasMany(players::class);
}
```

to

```
public function players()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Players');
}
```

Comment: both ways work, although I usually favor the first way(::class way) because it would make future reactors easier

Answer (score 0):

stats is a relationship and relationships are not loaded by default; you should change your query in the controller to load the relationship. use this:

```
$player_stats = players::where('bot', '=', '0')->with('stats')
->orderBy('ID', 'DESC')->limit('500')->get();
```

EDIT:
based on comments, you should tell laravel which columns to use for the relationship. and also the relationship was defined in reverse. try this:

change your relationships too:

```
class players extends Model
{
    protected $player = 'players';

    public function stats()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(stats::class, 'player', 'username');
    }
}

class stats extends Model
{
    protected $player = 'stats';

    public function players()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(players::class, 'player', 'username');
    }     
}
```

Comment: could you add your tables' schema in the question?

Comment: i'am not made in database migration, I made in mysql database

Comment: i don't see a stats_id in players table, what is the foreign key column in that table?

Comment: username in players and player in stats

Comment: the unique key is username in players and player in stats

Comment: i changed the answer; the relationship was defined in a wrong manner

Comment: I think the error is because you are defining the relationship wrong. I suggest you read the laravel docs on one-to-many relationships, and specially pay attention to second and third arguments of the belongsTo and hasMany functions